# Can you use and understand the meaning of this sentence without using "too"?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-meaning

Please consider this sentence:

> Is this motorcycle heavy to handle for a 5'10'' guy with around 60 Kg
> weight?

Now I guess you understood what I mean by this sentence. I want to ask if this motorcycle is too heavy to handle.

But, as you can see I skipped *too*. So does it still make sense in casual English?

OR neglecting *too* will make people perceive in opposite way, for example like this:

> Is this motorcycle heavy **enough** to handle for a 5'10'' guy with around 60 Kg
> weight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With out "too" it asks if the bike will be heavy, not if it will be *too heavy*.

It would be a rather unclear question. Does the heaviness of the bike depend on the person. I could imagine the reply being

> {pause} errr yeah, well it's a bike. So, yeah, it's heavy. Do you mean will it be too heavy?

It is also the sort of mistake that a native speaker is unlikely to make.  The expression "too heavy to handle" and similar ones are firmly idiomatic. It's not likely that a native speaker would miss out the word "too".

On the other hand, in a written context, the familiarity of the idiom may mean that a reader who is skim-reading may not even notice the the missing word. It is well-known that missing or duplicated words can be very hard to spot. But it is impossible to know if the error will be noticed, or how it will be interpreted by any third party.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, the mistake happened here https://www.reddit.com/r/motorcycles/comments/p7wt1q/is_this_motorcycle_heavy_to_handle_for_a_510_guy/ I asked a question and got all answers. I really liked answers but later realized I didn't use "too" in title. I can't even edit it. Now I'm overthinking if they gave answer to my problem or they answered opposite thing :( I made things complicated for myself. I'm very worried now.

Comment: Yes. Heavy to handle - it takes effort and care but I can do it. Too heavy to handle - I can't do it. The difference is crucial.

Comment: So, I wanted to make sure if native users can still perceive it correctly or they mistake it with "heavy enough".

Comment: Also it would be rude to ask them again what they understood.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey thanks. How much is the possibility that native speakers will perceive it as "heavy enough" (means I want to a heavy motorcycle)?

Comment: @Vikas - that is very unlikely. Someone who wanted a motorcycle that was 'heavy enough' to handle (whatever _that_ means) would say  so.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey :D so should I assume users on Reddit perceived my problem correctly?

Comment: @Vikas  We cannot comment on what Reddit users might perceive.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I understand :) Sorry.

Comment: Did you spot the duplicated word in the last paragraph?

Comment: @JamesK LOL! No! How did you do that magic?  So you mean by last paragraph that native speakers will tend to fast-read it as "too heavy to handle"?

Comment: Yes, when skim reading you tend to look at the main words and fill in the gaps using your knowledge of grammar and idiom. This is why proofreading is a difficult skill that has to be learned.  A proofreader has to turn off the "fill in the gaps" ability of their brain and look at what is actually written.